# Two Django apps in Nginx

Tags: django, sockets, nginx

I'm trying to deploy two different applications using Nginx. I deployed the first app some weeks ago, I'm trying to deploy a new one. The next are the first app. I deployed the first app using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-django-con-postgres-nginx-y-gunicorn-en-ubuntu-18-04-es)

**gunicorn.socket** *(first application socket file)*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket    

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**gunicorn.service** *(first application service file)*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=geanmuri
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/geanmuri/first_app/web_app      
ExecStart=/home/geanmuri/first_app/.venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          analisistweets.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**app_covid.socket** *(second app socket file)*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket     

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/app_covid.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**app_covid.service** *(second app service file)*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=app_covid.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=geanmuri
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/geanmuri/app_covid     
ExecStart=/home/geanmuri/app_covid/.venv/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/run/app_covid.sock \
          predictor_corona_web.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The first app is working OK, but when I try to start the second socket I failing.

```sh
$ sudo systemctl start app_covid.socket
$ Job for app_covid.socket failed.
$ See "systemctl status app_covid.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Status**

```
$ systemctl status app_covid.socket
● app_covid.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app_covid.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: /run/app_covid.sock (Stream)
```

**Permissions**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  429 ago 25 10:47  app_covid.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  113 ago 24 22:06  app_covid.socket
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  438 jul  9 18:50  gunicorn.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 jul  9 18:32  gunicorn.socket
```

I don't know what's happening. Thanks for advice.

**EDIT**

I posted it, after follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@caterinadmitrieva/serving-multiple-django-apps-on-second-level-domains-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-a4a14804174c) to deploy both apps.

Comment: Out if intrest can you start app_covid when gunicorn isnt running as you may be prevented from running both on the same server.

Comment: Can you show the output of `systemctl status app_covid.socket`  ?

Comment: @blobbymatt, Should I stop gunicorn service and start both before restart nginx?

Comment: @Charlesthk, I just edit the post with the status at the bottom.

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo thanks, can you compare file permissions for `/run/app_covid.sock` and for `/run/gunicorn.sock` ?

Comment: There's not a `/run/app_covid.sock` file :( @Charlesthk